# NestJS, typeorm array filtering

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to filter ads through tags that exist within tagList, but when I try it only detects the first element inside the array `tagList[]`.

This is my entity:

```js
import { UserEntity } from '@app/user/entities/user.entity';
import { Comment } from '@app/ad/comment.entity';
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  BeforeUpdate,
  ManyToOne,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
@Entity({ name: 'ads' })
export class AdEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  slug: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  subject: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  title: string;

  @Column('simple-array')
  type: string[];

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  hourlyRate: number;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  location: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  aboutAuthor: string;

  @Column('simple-array')
  requiredSkills: string[];

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column('simple-array')
  tagList: string[];

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  reccCount: number;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  studentNumber: number;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateTimestamp() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
  }
  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.ads, { eager: true })
  author: UserEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.ad, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  comments: Comment[];
}
```

This is how I'm trying to filter inside of my service:

```js
 async findAll(
    currentUserId: number,
    query: any,
  ): Promise<AdsResponseInterface> {
    const queryBuilder = getRepository(AdEntity)
      .createQueryBuilder('ads')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('ads.author', 'author');
    if (query.tags) {
      const tags = query.tags.split(',');
      queryBuilder.andWhere('ads.tagList IN (:...tags)', { tags });
    }
```

Suppose my tagList has ["hello", "test"],
when I look for hello or test it doesn't work, but looking for hello,test it works.